# Can't run a MongoDB image in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am going to use MongoDB for my personal project and connect it with my local code.
I created a container using command below:

```
docker run --name mymongo -d mongo -e MONGODB_DATABASE=namemongo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor -p 27019:27017
```

But it didn't start. Output of command `docker container ls -a`:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
5bbcbce61c28   mongo     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Exited (2) 54 seconds ago             mymongo
```

`docker exec -it 5bbcbce61c28 /bin/bash`:

```
Error response from daemon: Container 5bbcbce61c284cc53b431e8d49e157b788ea6f0f70d57ca13aeefe5757c01983 is not running
```

I tried a `docker start 5bbcbce61c28`(it returns `5bbcbce61c28`), but when i try command above it has similar error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all the docker options before the image name like this

```
docker run --name mymongo -d -e MONGODB_DATABASE=namemongo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=toor -p 27019:27017 mongo
```

Comment: Oh, this is weird, thanks!